# "Request for access" messages coming from my Google Docs add-on users

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I developed a Google Docs add-on that is now fairly popular (300k installed users, https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/onelook_thesaurus/372652075936). Since Sept 30, 2019, I have been receiving sharing requests for the Apps Script source code of this add-on, directly from the email addresses of end users.  I have received a few dozen of these over the last month to my developer email address.

I'm not sure what triggers the sharing request, but I don't think these end users are developers, or even aware of the Apps Script code.  I believe the sharing requests are being created programmatically by the Google Docs backend, possibly due to some error condition, but I am at a loss trying to replicate the problem or identify the source of it.

This is problematic since these users do not intend to share their email addresses with me.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an add-on with 35K users. Perhaps we need to put it into the Google bug tracker. Did you try that?